# Programming on Bluetooth module

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, spp

Now I have a Bluetooth module which support SPP, I want it to support BLE 4.0. Can I program on it? How can I start? In fact I want it to connect to iOS app, but I don't want to be included in MFI, that's the only solution I figured out.

Comment: For BLE you need to use CoreBluetooth and no MFi is needed. Check out the official programming guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

You can connect bluetooth module to jailbroken iOS device without MFI program membership.
I used [this](https://code.google.com/p/btstack/wiki/iPhoneBluetooth) BT stack library to establish BT connection

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right you have a module which supports SPP and you want it to support BLE? I don't believe that is possible. The serial port profile is not part of the BLE spec. I am guessing you have a BT 2.0 module. 
You need to have a module that supports BLE or is running the BLE stack before you can connect to it to begin with. To use the module you have now, you need MFI to connect to an iPhone over SPP.
In summary, the two options you have are:

- Keep the module you have (BT 2.0), join the MFI program or jailbreak to use SPP
- Get a BLE module and use CoreBluetooth without the need to join the MFI